# Is there an equivalent of "blah" + variable + "blah" in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This actually works:

```
<div ng-include="'/partials/' + items.my_filename + '.html'"></div>
```

But even though it finds the file it still gives me an error:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/partials/.html 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm glad it works but does anyone know how to get rid of the error?

EDIT: it's pulling the variable from a remote database, could the delay be causing the error?

EDIT2: Yep, that's what's causing it.  I think this is a question for Firebase.

Comment: Do you seriously have a file `partials/.html`? No filename?

Comment: No I don't, I have partials/test.html and the variable is "test".  It works fine but still gives me the 404

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure that `items.my_filename` is `test`?

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out, it's getting the "test" variable from Firebase and there's a delay, so a first it thinks it can't find it, until it does.  I still don't know how to get rid of the error but that's what's causing it.

Comment: did you get your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="items.my_filename" ng-include="'/partials/' + items.my_filename + '.html'"></div>
```

Example: **With** `ng-if`:  http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/daFhp/1/  Notice only one call, with the file name (which would work if that file was there).

Example: **Without** `ng-if`:  http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/daFhp/  Notice the two calls, one without the var/file name.  One with the file name (which would work if that file was there).

I am using `$timeout` in the examples to simulate delay in AJAX calls.

`ng-if` prevents the bad call.

**UPDATE**
Newer versions of AngularJS (1.2.0-rc3+) will have problems when you have `ng-if` on the same element as `ng-include`.  To fix this you can simply wrap your `ng-include` element in an element with `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-if="items.my_filename">
    <div ng-include="'/partials/' + items.my_filename + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close! For some reason I needed to do it a little differently:  `var testRef = new Firebase('https://mydatabase.firebaseio-demo.com/test');
testRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
 $scope.test = snapshot.val();
});` then `ng-if="test"`  More to do with Firebase than Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that `ng-include`, given a `null` argument, will just do nothing.

As a result you could go this way

```
<div ng-include="partialPath"></div>
```

with, for instance

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.partialPath = null;

  $http.get(...).success(function (data) {
     $scope.partialPath = '/partials/' + data.my_filename + '.html';
  });
});
```

*Or* you could also use a filter like this (very good for re-use)

```
app.filter('partialize', function () {
  return function (name) {
    return name ? '/partials/' + name + '.html' : null;
  };
});
```

with the following partial definition

```
<div ng-include="my_filename | partialize"></div>
```